# Insert data in child object using Dapper

Tags: dapper

I have the following classes

```
public class TenantUser
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public TenantInformation TenantInfo { get; set; }
}

public class TenantInformation
{
    public string InstitutionId { get; set; }
    public string InstitutionName { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to retrieve information using Dapper successfully:

```
string query = "select tu.UserId, tu.InstitutionId, ti.InstitutionName 
        from tenantuser as tu " 
        + "inner join tenantinfo ti on ti.InstitutionId = tu.InstitutionId";

var res = d.Query<TenantUser, TenantInformation, TenantUser>(query, (tu, ti) =>
{ tu.TenantInfo = ti; return tu; }, "InstitutionId");
```

How would I insert data into the TenantUser table?

I tried this:

```
var tenantUser = new TenantUser();
tenantUser.UserId = "testuser@mail.com";
tenantUser.TenantInfo = 
      d.Query<TenantInformation>("select * from tenantinfo").First(); //This works
tenantUser.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;

string query = 
    "insert into tenantUser values(@userid, @institutionid, @lastactivitydate)";
d.Execute(query, tenantUser);
```

Since `InstitutionId` is a property in the child object `TenantInfo` i get the 
**error: "Must declare the scalar variable \"@institutionid\".**

How would I fix this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dapper is deliberately simplistic. In your scenario, you would have to *flatten the data* - at least for the `insert`:

```
d.Execute(query, new {
    userid = tenantUser.UserId,
    institutionid = tenantUser.TenantInfo.InstitutionId,
    lastactivitydate = tenantUser.LastActivityDate
});
```